# Can we say that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

For two functions $f(x), g(x): \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^n$, assume that for any $x \in \mathbb R$, $$f(x)\le g(x) $$ and also $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)<\infty$. Can we say that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)<\infty$?

Sorry for this seems trivial question. In my view, I think that
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)\le \lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)<\infty
$$

So that should be existence of limit of $f(x)$. But why the someone said that we must show that existence of the limit of $f(x)$, then we can take the limit...

Comment: First, the definitions here don't make sense. Ignoring that issue, $\limsup f <\infty$

Comment: @Andrew What do you mean the definitions does not make sense?

Comment: @Andrew Is there another way to prove the existence of the limit?

Comment: There is no guarantee $f$ has a limit. Consider $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $g=1$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams So is there any another way to prove the existence of limit?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Can we use the Cauchy Criterion? Like for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $T>0$, so that $s>t>T$, $|f(s)-f(t)|\le \epsilon$, then $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)<\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take $n=1$. $f(x) = \sin (x)$ and $g(x) = 1$.

It is well known that $f(x)\leq g(x)$ (because $\sin$ takes values in $[-1,1]$) and clearly $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} g(x) = 1$.

But in general $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$ does not exists. Indeed, if you take the sequence $2\pi n$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(2\pi n) = 0$, but if you take $2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}) = 1$.

Comment: So is there another way to check the existence of the limit of $f(x)$ like Cauchy?

Comment: @Hermi All you can say is that if the limit exists, it must be smaller than $g$. The limit would exist if for instance $f$ was a monotone increasing function.

Comment: Can you please see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4775924/is-there-any-other-like-cauchy-criterion-to-show-that-existence-of-the-limit

Comment: Can we use the Cauchy Criterion? Like for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $T>0$, so that $s>t>T$, $|f(s)-f(t)|\le \epsilon$, then $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)<\infty$?

Comment: @Hermi Oh I see, I'll answer there (actually not now I hope in an hour will be ok)