# Is there any other like Cauchy Criterion to show that existence of the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $f(t)$ be a function from $R$ to $R^d$. Assume that there is a constant $M>0$ so that
$$
|f'(t)|\le Mu(t),
$$
where $u(t)$ is a continuous function and $\int_0^\infty u(s)ds<\infty$.

I try to prove the existence of the limit
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)
$$.

Here I write
$$
f(t)=f(0)+\int_0^t f'(s)ds\le f(0)+\int_0^t |f'(s)|ds\le f(0)+\int_0^t M u(s)ds.
$$

So the issue is that we cannot just take the limit. So is there any other like Cauchy Criterion to show that existence of the limit?

Comment: Note that $|f(t) - f(s)| \le \int_s^t |f'(r)| dr \le M \int_s^t u(r) dr$ because $\int_0^\infty u(r) dr < \infty$ one can set $s,t$ large enough such that the difference is small as one desires i.e. you prove that the sequence is Cauchy, hence it converges because of completeness.

Comment: @user807606 Yes. But how to choose such $N$ so that $s>t>N$, we have $|f(t)-f(s)|\le \epsilon$?

Comment: You ''don't'' (explicitly at least!). Because $\int_0^\infty u(r) dr < \infty$, we know that there exists $N > 0$ such that $\int_N^\infty u(r) dr < \varepsilon / M$, then use that $N$ and $s > t > N$ to get $|f(t) - f(s)| \le \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point here is that since $|f'|$ is always non-negative, the function

$$F(t):= \int_0^t |f'(s)| ds$$ is monotone increasing.

Therefore, the limit $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} F(t)$ exists, but could be infinite. You can find a proof here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Monotone_Real_Function/Increasing

Now we prove that the limit can not be infinite. Let $K:=\int_0^\infty u(t) dt$.

If by contradiction $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} F(t) = \infty$, then there exists $T$ such that for all $t>T$ we have $F(t)>MK+1$.

Now, since $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^t u(t) dt = K$ we can find $T'$ so that for all $t>T'$ we have $\int_0^t Mu(t) dt \leq MK+\frac{1}{2}$.

Let $t> \max\{T,T'\}$, then $F(t) > MK+1 > MK+\frac{1}{2} \geq \int_0^t u(t) dt$ which contradicts your last inequality.